# After a password reset on a MacBook with a FileVault recovery key, can I access new changes in my iCloud Keychain without logging in to iCloud again?

Tags: icloud, security, password, keychain, filevault

Alternate phrasing of the core question: Where exactly is that secret stored which provides a MacBook with access to one’s iCloud account one previously logged in to?

I have a MacBook Pro (14", 2021) with FileVault 2 enabled. For recovery, I set up a recovery key. I gathered the following information so far about resetting a user’s local password:

- A password reset by a local administrator [resets one’s login keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1086/mac).
- A password reset using a FileVault recovery [key also resets one’s login keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh35902/mac).

Assuming the only requirement of accessing the iCloud Keychain is having some locally (per-device) stored iCloud login secret: can I access the latest version of my iCloud Keychain without logging in again to iCloud? If this iCloud login secret is stored in my login keychain, then the answer is no, since it is accessible neither to my admin nor via FileVault recovery (as the login keychain has been reset by the password reset). Is it really stored there? I found some entry in Keychain Access that seems to be this secret, but I’m not sure and I didn’t find any information about this either.

(If the administrator or the one resetting my password via FileVault recovery can access that version of the iCloud Keychain that is *locally cached on the device*, but cannot acquire new changes, than it is not a problem: I can simply reset all passwords that are stored in the iCloud Keychain, so the locally cached version will contain passwords that are no longer valid. This question is about acquiring new changes from the iCloud Keychain after a local password reset.)